# How can I show a Tipsy tooltip automatically on load and close it after 10 seconds?

Tags: jquery, tipsy

Is there any way how to show a [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) tooltip automatically on load and close it after 10 seconds?

```
<img class="west" title="Click here to upload a photo" src="/images/nophoto.jpg" alt="" />
```

```js
$('.west').tipsy({ gravity: 'w', html: true, live: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.west').tipsy('show');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.west').tipsy('hide');
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: It does not now the tooltip.